# Select a random element from a dynamic array in HTML

Tags: html, random, checkbox

I'd like to add HTML to a Google Site that allows a user to press a button that displays a random letter of the alphabet. However, it should randomize only the letters that the user selects through checkboxes. Below is an image of what I'd like to achieve, and I'd like the result to display to the right of the checkbox array.

[image]

As to what I have tried so far, I have the following code that I modified from an open source online. I hope it is ok for my purpose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Pick Letters To Randomize</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" id="letter1" name="letter1" >
  <label for="letter1"> A</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="letter2" name="letter2" >
  <label for="letter2"> B</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="letter3" name="letter3" >
  <label for="letter3"> C</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Randomize">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am really at a loss for how to solve the rest of my problem.

Comment: Randomize one letter? Randomize them all? Can you explain the logic more?

Comment: Hi, I want to randomize one letter, but only from the boxes that are checked. So, in the picture example above, pressing the button would return either A or B. But if all three boxes were checked, then it would return either A, B, or C. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for you. I have a few suggestions that I've implemented that will make this easier for you:

Add a value to the checkbox input. That way, you don't have to grab a child/sibling label.

I've added comments to show what I'm doing. Hope that helps!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

const form = document.getElementById("randomLetterForm");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("randomSubmit");
const textResult = document.getElementById("result");


// We check the values on the submit click
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Prevent it from *actually* submitting (e.g. refresh)
  e.preventDefault();
  // Grab *all* selected checkboxed into an array
  const items = document.querySelectorAll("#randomLetterForm input:checked");
  // Checking if it's not empty
  if (items.length > 0) {
    // Setting a random index from items[0] to items[items.length]
    textResult.innerHTML = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)].value;
  } else {
    // If not, we alert
    alert("Please choose at least 1 number");
  }
  
});
});
```

```html
<h1>Pick Letters To Randomize</h1>

<form id="randomLetterForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A" id="letter1" name="letter1" >
  <label for="letter1"> A</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="B" id="letter2" name="letter2" >
  <label for="letter2"> B</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value= "C" id="letter3" name="letter3" >
  <label for="letter3"> C</label><br><br>
  <input id="randomSubmit" type="submit" value="Randomize">
</form>
<div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! But how exactly do I use the two blocks of code together; I want to embed on a website.

Comment: You'd paste the HTML exactly like that on whatever HTML editor you're using for your website, and you'd add the JS wherever your JS is being served. There's so many different ways to do it, that one couldn't possibly know how you're gonna do it without knowing the details of your setup. I'll wrap the code in a ready state as well,  just to make things consistent. :)

Comment: Ok, I normally use the embed box that comes with Google Sites to input the HTML. I think i figured it out though; I have to put the JS in a <script> tag within the HTML.

Comment: You can do that as well. I'm not sure what you're using for your website, so it's anybody's guess. Do you have some more info? That should work though. :)

Comment: Yes I'm building it using Google's website app. There's a simple embed box in the tools that lets you put HTML in, so that's what I use, and I'm learning through doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad you got it sorted. :)